# get the jquery widget instance from an element inside the widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a widget with Jquery widget factory. The short version of code is like this:

```
_create: function(){
    this.element.hide(); //hide original input
    this.newInput=$("<input>"); //new one
    this.element.before(this.newInput); //add the new one
},
onFocusOut: function(){
    if($(this).val()) ???.takeData();
},
takeData: function(){
    this.element.val()=this.newInput.val();
}
```

The 'this' in onFocusOut is a reference to the input field and NOT to the widget itself. How can I call the takeData function of the widget? How can I get the reference to the widget where 'this' is a part of?

Thx, Mike :-)

Answer (score 0):

Find the `widget` ancestor for the element using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). Assuming your widget has a `widget` class:

```
this.closest('.widget').takeData();
```

Comment: ok, good idea. Wont work for me because I actualy have more than one 'newInputs' bundled inside a DIV. But I can do `this.parent().closest('.widget')`.
This line helps referencing the field, but not the widget instance.
Adding `.myWidget("instance")` do the job.
Complete line: `this.parent().closest('.widget').myWidget("instance").takeData()`
Thx @msg for your hint :-)